# Format utcnow() in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I format dynamic content utcnow() to something like this “2021-06-01 13:42:59” in ADF. I have tried “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss” but it doesn’t work.

Comment: utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') should work - can you show your configuration and results?

Comment: This is my config in http request id=PONT_01&typedata=greentime&start=2021-06-01%2000%3A00%3A00&end=formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') and it returns a file that contains this error {"error":"time data \"formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')\" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"}

Comment: Your request is sending the literal value "formatDateTime(...)" function rather than the function results.

Comment: My post api date is in this format “2021-06-01 13:42:59”. Is it possible to make it dynamic to today’s date?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use concatenation or sting interpolation to insert the return value of the function. Can you post a screen shot from the Web activity where you are specifying the payload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Joel mentioned, you can use the inbuilt date function utcnow(). Click on "Add dynamic content" and select the "utcnow" under the date functions. Then add the formatting like 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' within the braces. Eventually you should have something like the attached picture.[image: Dynamic content]
[image: Date function utcnow]
[image: final setting]